# How to join Urdu alphabets in c#

Tags: c#, urdu

i am developing an urdu based application using c#. i have done with segmentation now problem is after segmentation i got letters of Urdu language any one give me idea how to join them to make words from letters like

- ب ڑ ی = بڑی
- ب  ا ت = بات

Comment: Is your question "how to use `String.Join` to join characters"? Your sample shows characters separated with spaces vs. same characters without spaces - so not very clear what exactly your problem is... Showing code you have problem with (and why it is any different from any other case like "a b c = abc") would make question much better.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe OP is talking about ligatures that join letters and change their shape (ie: like Arabic, etc).  Agree that we need to see the code that produces the problem.  A good Urdu font should have many thousands of ligatures to properly render words.  This may not be a programming problem so much as it is a font and layout problem.  Most common fonts only support naskh type style, not nastaliq, if that's what this is about.

Comment: No in urdu words combine to make words and i gave just an example with spaces there is no use of space. in segmentation i got a large number of alphabets i have to make valid words from these alphabets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply be able to concatenate letters into words.  Just make sure there is no whitespace and the letters should join together properly automatically.

```
 string a = "ب";
 string b = "ڑ";
 string c = "ی";
 textBox1.Text = a + b + c;
```

produces :

[image]

Comment: thanks it might be a solution but i need to check if the word is valid too after joining

Comment: @user3599590 you want to check it against a dictionary?  Like spell checking?

Comment: yes exactly it was so difficult to put in words but you got me right

Comment: @user3599590 Well, that is MUCH more difficult.  I'm not sure if the Urdu localized MS Office supports this?  Office interop might be an option.  Otherwise I would look for 3rd party solutions - something like : http://www.cle.org.pk/software/langproc/spellcheck.htm  <<- This is C++ but there is a DLL and API that you can use in C#.

Comment: thanks a lot j.. your help is much appreciated....